# Where was Jeff Nuttall's "Bomb Culture" discussed in Parliament?

Tags: quote-source, bomb-culture, jeff-nuttall

A fact frequently mentioned about Jeff Nuttall's book *Bomb Culture* (1968) is that it was the subject of a discussion in Parliament, e.g. in [an article announcing a Nuttall exhibition at a library](https://www.staffnet.manchester.ac.uk/news/events-activities/display/?id=16982)
or in [*British Terrorist Novels of the 1970s*](https://books.google.de/books?id=tYpWDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA90&lpg=PA90&dq=nuttall%20%22bomb%20culture%22%20parliament&source=bl&ots=t2yWbyHbta&sig=ACfU3U1c3IQ2YdMWaV_AkZ5q_6k6yAmKcw&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiBvs29yt3wAhVGh_0HHSRiCzEQ6AEwEXoECAcQAw#v=onepage&q=nuttall%20%22bomb%20culture%22%20parliament&f=false)

Hansard's records of the debates from the House of Commons and the House of Lords can be [viewed and searched online](https://hansard.parliament.uk/). I haven't been able to find a debate where Nuttall's book is mentioned. I'd be grateful for any help finding the debate that discussed *Bomb Culture*.

Comment: [This source](https://www.creativetourist.com/event/off-beat-jeff-nuttall-john-rylands-library/) says the book was "criticised in parliament in 1970 as part of a debate on youth culture". Might help to narrow the search.

Comment: [Even more specific](https://www.literaryheist.com/articles/jeff-nuttall-mind-bombs-and-mimeographs/): "*debating the puzzling attitudes and behaviour of the youth of the day, the House of Commons cited Bomb Culture as a primary source of information since it clearly stated that a “generation that has grown up under the ever-present threat of nuclear extinction could hardly be expected to think or behave as if it had a future ahead of it.”*" I still couldn't find anything in Hansard.

Comment: The source of the quote appears to be the frontispiece of Nuttall's own book :-)